# Why the bootstrap filter is inefficient when the prior is vague or the likelihood picky?

Tags: bootstrap, particle-filter

I am reading these [notes](http://www.zabaras.com/Courses/BayesianComputing/SMC4SmoothingAndAPF.pdf) about Sequentially Monte Carlo for state space model.

On page 14 it says that "The SMC algorithm discussed earlier is very inefficient. This is particularly true for vague prior $ f(x_n|x_{n-1}) $ or picky likelihood $ g(y_n|x_n) $. [If the importance distribution is $ f(x_n|x_{n-1})$ ]".

I would like to ask if you could explain this to me (with an example if it is possible).

Comment: This is rather clearly explained in those notes: if you do not account for the value $y_n$ when making a proposal for $x_n$, the density value $g(y_n|x_n)$ will appear in the importance weight. When this function varies quickly with $x_n$ the importance weights will most often be zero and the filter will degenerate quite quickly.

Comment: Inefficient as in high variance of $W_n = \frac{g(y_n|x_n)f(x_n|x_{n-1})}{\hat{p}(x_n|y_n,x_{n-1})}$ if you set $\hat{p}(x_n|y_n,x_{n-1})$ equal to $f(x_n|x_{n-1})$. To be clear they're talking about the variance with respect to the density $\hat{p}(x_n|y_n,x_{n-1})$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So, if the data are very informative then some weights may be too high. When the prior is vague how does this affect the inefficency?